# How should I setup a table of temporary/transactional items that I only need for a few days or weeks?

Tags: sql-server

We have created a table in Sql Server 2012 that we use to store temporary records of transactions with our integration partners. These records can be text, XML or BLOBs. They're not actually used for anything by our software but are for debugging, recovery and investigation purposes. After a certain age they are deleted.

As volume has increased recently, this table has grown immensely in size (50GB at the moment, individual rows are as much as 25MB). This is not a problem in itself. However, the deletion scripts that clear out old records are no longer running to completion in reasonable amounts of time.

Is there a better way to store and clean up this data? Would partitioning be useful for this? Is there some other technology that would help manage a rolling date range of large data?

Comment: Stored procedure and probably a view instead of a table?

Comment: You could have a cursor written, so as to it deletes some 'n' number of rows at a time. And put that cursor in an SP. That would specifically be ran from a job which can be ran every day to delete the records prior to the last 15 days. That also serves an advantage that only a single day records would be deleted. Thoughts ??

Comment: @RamMehta I actually have tried deleting using TOP: DELETE TOP [#] WHERE ... This initially works but slows down over time as well.

Comment: What you're describing sounds like a standard pattern for a "keep n", so nothing crazy there. Are your delete criteria indexed? Is this a heap or a clustered table?

Comment: The delete criteria are not indexed. PK is clustered. So I probably need to add indices to the Date, Type and Provider fields. However, won't those indices need to be rebuilt/recalculated? Will that eventually cause a similar slowdown?

Comment: Can you please tell me retention of online data, so that I can suggest you best??

Comment: The C in ACID stands for "consistent". One implication of that is that indexes are kept up to date with any data modifications that you do. So, in short, once you create the index, there's nothing else you need to do to keep it accurate.

Comment: @BenThul Thanks! I wasn't concerned about accuracy, rather, about the indices becoming unbalanced/etc. because of the deletions and thus needing to be rebuilt because they were slow/large/etc.

Comment: @RajeshRanjan A week to a month.

Answer (score 1):

First, check execution plan for DELETE - may be you'll get additional ideas.

Second, I suggest you to choose from two standard patterns for such tables.

1. Use [DELETE TOP(N)](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175486(v=sql.105).aspx) to remove data. N should be chosen
   experimentally.
2. Use set of tables (e.g. 10 tables) to store data by day or week and "rotate" it periodically. In this case you can [TRUNCATE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177570.aspx) "old" tables which is much faster than DELETE.

Comment: Thx! As noted in a comment above, I've tried option 1, DELETE TOP, with initially good results (table isn't locked as long but eventually the script never completes). Option 2 seems like manually implemented partitioning to me.

Comment: Did you use `DELETE TOP (N) ... ORDER BY DateColumn;`? Is there an index on the `DateColumn` to find the (N) rows without a table scan?

Comment: Make sure you also use a raw number in the top and not a variable. The execution plans come out different.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Enterprise Edition then Partitioning is the best idea to perform archiving when you have fixed retention of data on production table.

Here is how it can be done in very easy way without increasing disk IO, size of transaction log file and in a second.

According to your scenario.

1. I created a database named `TestPartition`.
2. Added 31 filegroup and data files to the database.
3. created Partition Function (`partition_fn_dayofMonth`) and Scheme `Partition_Sch_DayofMonth`.
4. Table named `tbl_TestArchive` (It's production table) on the partition scheme.
5. Temp table named `tbl_TestArchive_temp` on same partition scheme.
6. As you need to keep one month's data on production. So, to schedule archiving
   a. Switch partition of next day to temp table (created on same partition) at off hour before 12:00 AM at night.
   b. truncate the temp table.

Here is the script that you can follow.

```
Create Database TestPartition;
go

use TestPartition;
go
alter database TestPartition add filegroup P1
alter database TestPartition add filegroup P2
alter database TestPartition add filegroup P3
alter database TestPartition add filegroup P4
alter database TestPartition add filegroup P5
alter database TestPartition add filegroup P6
alter database TestPartition add filegroup P7
alter database TestPartition add filegroup P8
alter database TestPartition add filegroup P9
alter database TestPartition add filegroup P10
alter database TestPartition add filegroup P11
alter database TestPartition add filegroup P12
alter database TestPartition add filegroup P13
alter database TestPartition add filegroup P14
alter database TestPartition add filegroup P15
alter database TestPartition add filegroup P16
alter database TestPartition add filegroup P17
alter database TestPartition add filegroup P18
alter database TestPartition add filegroup P19
alter database TestPartition add filegroup P20
alter database TestPartition add filegroup P21
alter database TestPartition add filegroup P22
alter database TestPartition add filegroup P23
alter database TestPartition add filegroup P24
alter database TestPartition add filegroup P25
alter database TestPartition add filegroup P26
alter database TestPartition add filegroup P27
alter database TestPartition add filegroup P28
alter database TestPartition add filegroup P29
alter database TestPartition add filegroup P30
alter database TestPartition add filegroup P31
GO

USE [master]
GO
ALTER DATABASE [TestPartition] ADD FILE ( NAME = N'P1', FILENAME = N'F:\SQLDB\p1.ndf' , SIZE = 3072KB , FILEGROWTH = 1024KB ) TO FILEGROUP [P1]
ALTER DATABASE [TestPartition] ADD FILE ( NAME = N'P2', FILENAME = N'F:\SQLDB\p2.ndf' , SIZE = 3072KB , FILEGROWTH = 1024KB ) TO FILEGROUP [P2]
ALTER DATABASE [TestPartition] ADD FILE ( NAME = N'P3', FILENAME = N'F:\SQLDB\p3.ndf' , SIZE = 3072KB , FILEGROWTH = 1024KB ) TO FILEGROUP [P3]
ALTER DATABASE [TestPartition] ADD FILE ( NAME = N'P4', FILENAME = N'F:\SQLDB\p4.ndf' , SIZE = 3072KB , FILEGROWTH = 1024KB ) TO FILEGROUP [P4]
ALTER DATABASE [TestPartition] ADD FILE ( NAME = N'P5', FILENAME = N'F:\SQLDB\p5.ndf' , SIZE = 3072KB , FILEGROWTH = 1024KB ) TO FILEGROUP [P5]
ALTER DATABASE [TestPartition] ADD FILE ( NAME = N'P6', FILENAME = N'F:\SQLDB\p6.ndf' , SIZE = 3072KB , FILEGROWTH = 1024KB ) TO FILEGROUP [P6]
ALTER DATABASE [TestPartition] ADD FILE ( NAME = N'P7', FILENAME = N'F:\SQLDB\p7.ndf' , SIZE = 3072KB , FILEGROWTH = 1024KB ) TO FILEGROUP [P7]
ALTER DATABASE [TestPartition] ADD FILE ( NAME = N'P8', FILENAME = N'F:\SQLDB\p8.ndf' , SIZE = 3072KB , FILEGROWTH = 1024KB ) TO FILEGROUP [P8]
ALTER DATABASE [TestPartition] ADD FILE ( NAME = N'P9', FILENAME = N'F:\SQLDB\p9.ndf' , SIZE = 3072KB , FILEGROWTH = 1024KB ) TO FILEGROUP [P9]
ALTER DATABASE [TestPartition] ADD FILE ( NAME = N'P10', FILENAME = N'F:\SQLDB\p10.ndf' , SIZE = 3072KB , FILEGROWTH = 1024KB ) TO FILEGROUP [P10]
ALTER DATABASE [TestPartition] ADD FILE ( NAME = N'P11', FILENAME = N'F:\SQLDB\p11.ndf' , SIZE = 3072KB , FILEGROWTH = 1024KB ) TO FILEGROUP [P11]
ALTER DATABASE [TestPartition] ADD FILE ( NAME = N'P12', FILENAME = N'F:\SQLDB\p12.ndf' , SIZE = 3072KB , FILEGROWTH = 1024KB ) TO FILEGROUP [P12]
ALTER DATABASE [TestPartition] ADD FILE ( NAME = N'P13', FILENAME = N'F:\SQLDB\p13.ndf' , SIZE = 3072KB , FILEGROWTH = 1024KB ) TO FILEGROUP [P13]
ALTER DATABASE [TestPartition] ADD FILE ( NAME = N'P14', FILENAME = N'F:\SQLDB\p14.ndf' , SIZE = 3072KB , FILEGROWTH = 1024KB ) TO FILEGROUP [P14]
ALTER DATABASE [TestPartition] ADD FILE ( NAME = N'P15', FILENAME = N'F:\SQLDB\p15.ndf' , SIZE = 3072KB , FILEGROWTH = 1024KB ) TO FILEGROUP [P15]
ALTER DATABASE [TestPartition] ADD FILE ( NAME = N'P16', FILENAME = N'F:\SQLDB\p16.ndf' , SIZE = 3072KB , FILEGROWTH = 1024KB ) TO FILEGROUP [P16]
ALTER DATABASE [TestPartition] ADD FILE ( NAME = N'P17', FILENAME = N'F:\SQLDB\p17.ndf' , SIZE = 3072KB , FILEGROWTH = 1024KB ) TO FILEGROUP [P17]
ALTER DATABASE [TestPartition] ADD FILE ( NAME = N'P18', FILENAME = N'F:\SQLDB\p18.ndf' , SIZE = 3072KB , FILEGROWTH = 1024KB ) TO FILEGROUP [P18]
ALTER DATABASE [TestPartition] ADD FILE ( NAME = N'P19', FILENAME = N'F:\SQLDB\p19.ndf' , SIZE = 3072KB , FILEGROWTH = 1024KB ) TO FILEGROUP [P19]
ALTER DATABASE [TestPartition] ADD FILE ( NAME = N'P20', FILENAME = N'F:\SQLDB\p20.ndf' , SIZE = 3072KB , FILEGROWTH = 1024KB ) TO FILEGROUP [P20]
ALTER DATABASE [TestPartition] ADD FILE ( NAME = N'P21', FILENAME = N'F:\SQLDB\p21.ndf' , SIZE = 3072KB , FILEGROWTH = 1024KB ) TO FILEGROUP [P21]
ALTER DATABASE [TestPartition] ADD FILE ( NAME = N'P22', FILENAME = N'F:\SQLDB\p22.ndf' , SIZE = 3072KB , FILEGROWTH = 1024KB ) TO FILEGROUP [P22]
ALTER DATABASE [TestPartition] ADD FILE ( NAME = N'P23', FILENAME = N'F:\SQLDB\p23.ndf' , SIZE = 3072KB , FILEGROWTH = 1024KB ) TO FILEGROUP [P23]
ALTER DATABASE [TestPartition] ADD FILE ( NAME = N'P24', FILENAME = N'F:\SQLDB\p24.ndf' , SIZE = 3072KB , FILEGROWTH = 1024KB ) TO FILEGROUP [P24]
ALTER DATABASE [TestPartition] ADD FILE ( NAME = N'P25', FILENAME = N'F:\SQLDB\p25.ndf' , SIZE = 3072KB , FILEGROWTH = 1024KB ) TO FILEGROUP [P25]
ALTER DATABASE [TestPartition] ADD FILE ( NAME = N'P26', FILENAME = N'F:\SQLDB\p26.ndf' , SIZE = 3072KB , FILEGROWTH = 1024KB ) TO FILEGROUP [P26]
ALTER DATABASE [TestPartition] ADD FILE ( NAME = N'P27', FILENAME = N'F:\SQLDB\p27.ndf' , SIZE = 3072KB , FILEGROWTH = 1024KB ) TO FILEGROUP [P27]
ALTER DATABASE [TestPartition] ADD FILE ( NAME = N'P28', FILENAME = N'F:\SQLDB\p28.ndf' , SIZE = 3072KB , FILEGROWTH = 1024KB ) TO FILEGROUP [P28]
ALTER DATABASE [TestPartition] ADD FILE ( NAME = N'P29', FILENAME = N'F:\SQLDB\p29.ndf' , SIZE = 3072KB , FILEGROWTH = 1024KB ) TO FILEGROUP [P29]
ALTER DATABASE [TestPartition] ADD FILE ( NAME = N'P30', FILENAME = N'F:\SQLDB\p30.ndf' , SIZE = 3072KB , FILEGROWTH = 1024KB ) TO FILEGROUP [P30]
ALTER DATABASE [TestPartition] ADD FILE ( NAME = N'P31', FILENAME = N'F:\SQLDB\p31.ndf' , SIZE = 3072KB , FILEGROWTH = 1024KB ) TO FILEGROUP [P31]
GO

USE TestPartition;
GO

CREATE PARTITION FUNCTION [partition_fn_dayofMonth](int) AS RANGE LEFT FOR VALUES (N'1', N'2', N'3', N'4', N'5', N'6', N'7', N'8', N'9', N'10', N'11', N'12', N'13', N'14', N'15', N'16', N'17', N'18', N'19', N'20', N'21', N'22', N'23', N'24', N'25', N'26', N'27', N'28', N'29', N'30', N'31')
GO

CREATE PARTITION SCHEME [Partition_Sch_DayofMonth] AS PARTITION [partition_fn_dayofMonth] TO ([P1], [P2], [P3], [P4], [P5], [P6], [P7], [P8], [P9], [P10], [P11], [P12], [P13], [P14], [P15], [P16], [P17], [P18], [P19], [P20], [P21], [P22], [P23], [P24], [P25], [P26], [P27], [P28], [P29], [P30], [P31], [PRIMARY])
GO

USE TestPartition;
GO
CREATE TABLE tbl_TestArchive
(
ColA varchar(8),
ColB varchar(8),
ColC varchar(8),
ColD varchar(8),
ColDate datetime,
day_of_month as day(ColDate) persisted
)
ON [Partition_Sch_DayofMonth](day_of_month)
GO

CREATE TABLE tbl_TestArchive_temp
(
ColA varchar(8),
ColB varchar(8),
ColC varchar(8),
ColD varchar(8),
ColDate datetime,
day_of_month as day(ColDate) persisted
)
ON [Partition_Sch_DayofMonth](day_of_month)
GO


---Create 10 records for each day start from 9th Aug 2016
USE TestPartition;
GO
declare @date datetime='2016-08-09'

while @date<'2016-09-09'
begin
insert into tbl_TestArchive values('ValueA','ValueB','ValueC','ValueD',@date)
set @date=DATEADD(dd,1,@date)
end
GO 10
--------------------------------------------------------
/*
Let say we need to keep only 1 month data on production.
So, what will we do?

We'll schedule a T-SQL batch to swith partition of next day to "tbl_TestArchive_temp" table at night at 11:55 PM (Off hour)
and we'll truncate it (tbl_TestArchive_temp).

This activity would not increase IO, Transaction Log file and will take a seccond to complete

Here is the query to switch partition
*/

USE TestPartition;
GO
Declare @partition int=day(dateadd(dd,1,getdate()));

ALTER TABLE tbl_TestArchive switch partition @partition to tbl_TestArchive_temp partition @partition;
GO

Truncate table tbl_TestArchive_temp;
GO
```

Thanks

Comment: It would be good to add that your suggestion needs the Enterprise edition. Otherwise they would have to roll their own, manual partitioning solution.

Comment: This looks like a good potential solution. I will give this a try as soon as possible. Thx!

Answer (score 0):

I know you are going to think that disable index will slow it down
Index maintenance is also slowing it down
What is the harm in trying

```
ALTER INDEX ALL ON table DISABLE;  
select 1
while (@@rowcount > 1)
begin
 delete top (100000) 
 from table 
 where  
end
ALTER INDEX ALL ON table rebuild;
```